# ListBox.SetBinding - ItemSourceProperty does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I use WPF in school project. Everything was just fine, until I tried to bind list to ListBox. I wrote some example code, where the issue appears.

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //make a new source
        myDataObject = new TestClass(DateTime.Now);
        Binding myBinding = new Binding("Students");
        myBinding.Source = myDataObject.Students;

        List<TestStudent> students = new List<TestStudent>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            students.Add(new TestStudent("name" + i, "surename" + i));
        }

        myDataObject.Students = students;

        myList.ItemsSource = myDataObject.Student; //this works

        myList.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding); //this doesn't show anything

    }
```

I have properly implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface. When I add some data this way to any TextBox.Text, it works fine. But when I try to bind list to ListBox.ItemsSource, result is empty box. Why does this happen? Thanks in advance for any advices.

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't just doing this in XAML

Comment: I need to change binding according to user actions and I am not so experienced to use triggers in XAML. I don't event know, if such thing could be done with XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Source` of the binding should be `myDataObject`, not `myDataObject.Students`. If you set `myDataObject.Students` as the source, the `ListBox` will try to bind to `myDataObject.Students.Students`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok, that works fine, thank you. But there are two another problems instead. First, changes int the list are updated with delay, if they are updated. Second - little mind blow - I have a button. When clicked, there is executed this line myDataObject.Students.RemoveAt(0);. This should remove first element of the list. But it removes elements for bottom of the list and usually removes none or more than one emelent at a time.

Comment: @Qerts, that's because `List<T>` doesn't send notifications when its content is modified, so there is no way for the binding system to detect the changes. Use an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead.